# Button to Open Floating layer [help]

Tags: html, css, button

need help getting this to have a button to open "floating colum layer" that will appear over image  an hide upon button click again
image is set to height 50% width 100% so float should be same and on top

code -> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jxVayJMX
to view go to cssdesk or scratchpad

(please use html/css only)
web design i cannot use anything but html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a div that contain your menu or something like this.... (Change the styles as you want)

```
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute;width:100%;background-color:black;color:white;top:0;left:0;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:16px;z-index:5;display:none">
// Put the menu items here

</div>
```

Also add a Id for your Navigation button like this

```
<button id="btnNav" type="button" class="button">Navigation</button>
```

Then write a Jquery Like this in ondocumentload or in a  tags.. Before that you have to give the location of the JQuery library

jQuery code is

```
var btnClick = 0;
$("#btnNav").click(function(){
    // On first button click, Open
    if(btnClick == 0)
    {
        $("#menu").show();
        btnClick = 1;        
    }else{
        //On second button click, hide.
        $("#menu").hide();
        btnClick = 0;      
    }

});
```

In here "btnNav" is the Identifier of the Navigation button and "menu" is the identifier of DIV that contains your menu.

tell me if you don't get it.... or i misread it.... and Plz Vote me up